# Azure pipeline copy data activity for copying data from Azure MSSQL to Azure MySQL

Tags: mysql, azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I'm aware that Azure Pipeline's Copy Data Activity does not support MySQL as sink. But is there any workaround via some other component to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the ammount of rows you are trying to copy. If you just need a few tables/rows, you may try with Azure Automation. That way you can just create a runbook with Powershell that connects to Azure Sql Server, queries the server and then sends that data to the Azure MySql Server. Then you can call the runbook from data factory using a webhook :)

If you end up going this route, remember that runbooks have a limitation and cannot run for more than 3 hours. More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#fair-share

Another option would be to create a custom activity for data factory. For this you need an Azure Batch pool. More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity

Hope this helped!